# Excel Advanced Filter: using OFFSET to create dynamic criteria range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I see that OFFSET can return a range, and Advanced Filter can use a Range as Criteria. But when I try create an dynamic range using OFFSET `OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),COUNTA(1:1))` and name it (_AF) then paste to Advanced Filter to use, Excel doesn't work. What did I do wrong? How can I fix it to use an OFFSET range as an dynamic range for Advanced Filter? 
[image: OFFSET]

[image: Ref not valid]

Comment: Try $A:$A  and $1:$1

Comment: @TonyStewart : it doesn't work too.